# socket.io chat example - trouble with form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to log a message entered in an input box in the console. I'm following the below example

http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

the problem i'm facing is when i type a message and click on send , the page automatically refreshes despite using 'return false' in the script. console.log also doesnt show 'message entered' which makes me believe that the script isnt getting invoked

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io();
    $('#chat-form').on('submit',function(){
      console.log('message entered');
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id='chat-form'>
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button type='submit'>Send</button>
    </form>
```

index.js

```
io.on('connection',function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('disconnect',function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

  socket.on('chat message',function(msg){
    console.log('message: '+msg)
  });

});
```

I even tried event.preventDefault(). but the page still refreshes on form submit.

Thanks,
KJ

Answer (score 0):

Check with F12 Tools/Firebug whatever if the javascript is run at all.

Answer (score 0):

At the time your script is run, `#chat-form` isn't present in the DOM yet (because the HTML *follows* the script).

Either move your `<script>` to right before `</body>` or wait for the [`ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) event before retrieving DOM elements:

```
var socket = io();
$(function() {
  $('#chat-form').on('submit',function(){
    console.log('message entered');
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
});
```